# How can I run all seeders within database/seeds folder automatically in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Instead adding all the new seeders files manually one by one into the DatabaseSeeder.php file, Is it possible to automatically run all files within the seeds directory. Is that possible?

PS: Of course (as @DissidentRage mentioned) in this case we **should** **consider** that automating such processes can make your seeders independent and can cause a lot trouble too.

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters but I imagine one reason people disapprove is because automating your seeder list means you run the risk of running interdependent seeders out of order. Something to consider.

Comment: Thank you @DissidentRage at least somebody gave a reason for the down votes. And you are actually right. Generally it is a bad thing to automating such processes but I thought because this is in development mode and it is actually under control I mean when you use seed you reset or recreate your database and you can just remove the last file and refresh. Thank you again for your comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I run in that question and found this way as an simple answer.

You can easily use [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to put all the filenames into an array and then loop through them just using foreach loop. And then call/run them all automatically. This way you don't need to add the new class to the `run()` method each time you create (mostly with `php artisan make:seeder SomeTableSeeder`) a seeder.

So instead:

```
// database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run() {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(AnotherTableSeeder::class);
        ...
    }

}
```

Simply use:

```
// database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run(){
        $files_arr = scandir( dirname(__FILE__) ); //store filenames into $files_array
        foreach ($files_arr as $key => $file){
            if ($file !== 'DatabaseSeeder.php' && $file[0] !== "." ){
                $this->call( explode('.', $file)[0] );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**PS:** If you want to exclude a seeder file from this auto run process, just add a single dot to the beginning of the filename.

**PS2:** If you want to change the excluder character **dot** for any reason. Just prepend your desired excluder character to the if expressions (like for underscore character prepend `&& $file[0] !== "_"`). **Don't change the `$file[0] !== "."` expression because it extends the scandir() methods  . and .. folders as well.**

Answer (score 4):

[Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding#calling-additional-seeders) has the following available method (`call`) you can use inside you `DatabaseSeeder.php`.

```
/**
 * Run the database seeders.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call([
        UserSeeder::class,
        PostSeeder::class,
        CommentSeeder::class,
    ]);
}
```

But to reiterate, running seeders like this might not be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `DatabaseSeeder.php` code-snippet I use to automatically execute revisions, it allows you to manipulate the order by adding a numeric version in front of the class-name.

After creating your seeder with `php artisan make:seeder` you can rename the seed-file

- From: `<orginal-classname>.php`
- To: `####-<orginal-classname>.php`

  - The size of your version-number does not matter

It's not required to change the actual class-name of the seeder.

```php
$seedFilePattern = '/([0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.php/i';
$files = scandir(dirname(__FILE__)); // Alphabetically sorted
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    if (!in_array($file, ['.', '..', 'DatabaseSeeder.php', 'BaseSeeder.php'])) {
        if (preg_match($seedFilePattern, $file, $matches)) {
            [, $version, $class] = $matches;
            $this->call($class);
        } else {
            echo '[WARNING] The file "' . $file . '" does not match the seeding pattern "' . $seedFilePattern . '", rename it accordingly to seed it automagically' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

My seeds dir for a given project

```
0001-abcSeeder.php
0002-defSeeder.php
0003-ghiSeeder.php
...
0008-xyzSeeder.php
BaseSeeder.php
DatabaseSeeder.php
```

If during development need to add something in between you just increase the size of that version ex: 00021

```
0001-abcSeeder.php
0002-defSeeder.php
00021-ForgotSomethingSeeder.php
0003-ghiSeeder.php
...
0008-xyzSeeder.php
BaseSeeder.php
DatabaseSeeder.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Most easy one -----------
as db:seed runs your databaseSeeder so,

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        if (env('APP_ENV') === 'testing') {
            // Testing Seeder
            $this->call([]);
        } elseif (env('APP_ENV') === 'local') {
            // Local Seeder [Dev]
            $this->call(array_merge($this->productionSeeder(), $this->devSeeder()));

        } else {
            // Production Seeder
            $this->call($this->productionSeeder());
        }

    }

    protected function devSeeder()
    {
        return [
            UserSeeder::class,
            anotherSeeder::class,
            -----
            -----
        ];
    }

    protected function productionSeeder()
    {
        return [
            UserSeeder::class,
            anotherSeeder::class,
            -----
            -----
        ];
    }
}
```